# How do i make the entire row of yajra datatable clickable in laravel ajax? That is each ENTIRE ROW clickable. The following is my sample code

Tags: ajax, laravel

$(function() {
           $('#tableDT').DataTable({
           processing: true,
           serverSide: true,
           ajax: '{{ route('customers') }}',
           columns: [
                    { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name' },
                    { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name' }
                 ]
        });
     });

Answer (score 0):

I coded an example for you, hope this is what you meant and might help you out.

```js
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger", "Nixon" ],
    [ "Garrett", " Winters" ],
    [ "Ashton", " Cox" ],
    [ "Cedric", " Kelly" ],
    [ "Airi", " Satou" ],
    [ "Thane", " Horton" ],
    [ "Burton", " Jackson" ],
    [ "Macaulay", " Cohen" ],
    [ "Steel", " Whitfield" ],
    [ "Travis", " Ochoa" ],
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected = [];                       

    $('#tableDT').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "First Name" },
            { title: "Last Name" },
        ],
        select: { style: 'multi' },          
        rowCallback: function( row, data ) { 
            if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        }
    } );
    
        $('#tableDT tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
 
        if ( index === -1 ) {
            selected.push( id );
        } else {
            selected.splice( index, 1 );
        }
 
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableDT">
<thead>

</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: I much appreciate your answer, i wanted to return data using the yajra datatable eg  $data = Sample_data::latest()->get();
            return DataTables::of($data)->make(true); This in my controller then return my sample code to fetch data from db. What i wanted is to use my jquery ajax code to make the table rows clickable and directs me to another link